# SQL Management Studio Task Import Data is greyed out

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Database: SQL2017 Express
Management Studio 18
System: x64
I have sysdmin / db owner etc & database is accessible/updateable.

[image]

**"This feature is not currently available in this version or the database is not available"**

I solved this by using (Menu start-> type "Import" which runs **DTSWizard.exe**), but it still doesnt work from SSMS.

Comment: i'm glad u helped but this is only workaround - not problem solution (no oledb/excel/access import)

Answer (score 7):

We can open the "SQL Server Import and Export Wizard" without the help of SQL Management Studio.

The path is something like this (depending on your version):

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>   18\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSIS\150\Binn\DTSWizard.exe"

Comment: Very much appreciate

Answer (score 5):

What version of SSMS do you have installed? I had the same problem with v18 preview 4 and rolled back to 17.9 which resolved the problem for me.

Comment: v18.0 Preview 4.  Build 15.0.18040.0

Comment: I'd suggest un-installing that version of SSMS and re-installing [17.9](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Running latest 18.1 and this option is still disabled

Comment: @pantonis did you install [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=13255)?

Comment: @feganmeister No. But why do I need to install these. Previous versions of SSMS did not need this

Comment: @feganmeister you need to install this if you don't have Microsoft Office installed and need to open .mdb files, also you can open the export wizard directly without SSMS:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSIS\150\Binn\DTSWizard.exe"

Answer (score 2):

Notice that you can also import data from files (for example CSV files) using the option you got there of "import flat file". A wizard will open and allow you to choose the file you want to import